# Putting HTML tags through js

Tags: javascript, html

I need to simply display some errors from my node server to the user, this is my code:

```
if(text.length > 1){
    text = text.join("<br>");
    console.log("array:",text);
}else{
    text = text[0];
}
```

and then I do:

```
myNewDiv.innerHTML = text;
```

and append it to the page, the problem is, that js converts the `<br>` into `&lt;br&gt;`, so the next errors are not displayed on new line, but like this:

```
some text br other text
```

Comment: if you are downvoting the question, could you atleast tell me why?

Comment: Can you show the code used to send this text to the browser? It's probably an encoding/decoding issue but we need to find the right function for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can send the HTML string in a different format from node, but this will work either way in your clientside code:

If you are using Jquery you can use:

```
function DecodeHtmlString(htmlString){
  return $('<div/>').html(htmlString).text();
}
```

Vanilla JS:

```
function DecodeHtmlString(htmlString){
  var temp = document.createElement("textarea");
  temp.innerHTML = htmlString;
  return temp.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the code you provided exactly what you are doing wrong, but here is a working version of what you are trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/03z6k7ko/

```
var text = ['Hello', 'world!'];

if(text.length > 1){
    text = text.join("<br/>");
}else{
    text = text[0];
}

document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = text;
```